# Do I need a new ESTA after aquiring dual citizenship?

Tags: usa, esta, dual-nationality

I am about to acquire Italian citizenship. When applying for an ESTA it asks you if you have any other nationalities. My current ESTA has around 20 months left. Do I need to reapply when I get the Italian citizenship?

I will still have my British citizenship when I acquire the Italian citizenship.

Comment: Is it Colin Firth asking? :)

Comment: @EdmundDantes you got me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Apply or change information in the Electronic System for Travel Authorization (ESTA)](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1073/~/apply-or-change-information-in-the-electronic-system-for-travel-authorization):

> If you obtain a new passport or change your name, gender or country of citizenship, you will be required to apply for a new travel authorization. This is also required if one of your answers to any of the VWP eligibility questions changes. The associated fee of $14 will be charged for each new application.

Note that "change your citizenship" could be better phrased as perhaps a "change in your citizenship circumstances" since it applies to your case. It really must, imagine country A is on the list the USA decided to not like this year. Now, if you got an ESTA as a citizen of B and gain citizenship of A as well but USA hates A people then they will want to take a good look at and possibly deny you because you now belong to A as well.

Comment: Thank you! Hopefully the USA wont hate either country, it's my favourite place to travel!

Comment: @SamJones I suspect that the author of the quoted passage was thinking about changing passports because of changed citizenship rather than changing your answer to the "other citizenships" question (the fields mentioned are used for the database lookup).  If you want to travel to the US on your Italian passport, of course you'll need a new ESTA.  But if you travel on your British passport with your current ESTA, I would guess there's an extremely high chance that everything would go perfectly smoothly.  But since the cost of getting a new ESTA is so low, it's not really worth risking it.

Comment: My instinct is that it isn't necessary here, since both passports are for EU countries, but it would be safer to get a new ESTA.